# SQL ODBC Connection in Excel - Error 08001 (Works in Cystal Reports?)

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, odbc, sql-server-express

I'm trying to create a report in Excel using an ODBC data connection to one of our SQL Server Express databases, but whenever I try to run a query I get the following error:

"ODBC: ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect())."

Having googled this rigorously, this error points to either the database not existing or me not having the correct permissions to the database. However, I have checked the permissions are correct, I have db_reader and db_writer permissions for the database, am permitted access to SQL Express, TCP is enabled on the SQL Server using port 1433, which I can telnet from my device. This ODBC connection is set up in exactly the same way as connections to our other databases, the only difference being these are SQL Server databases not SQL Server Express databases.

What's more is I can query data using this ODBC connection perfectly fine in Crystal Reports, it just seems to be Excel giving me this issue. I'm scratching my head, as every solution I can find online has been accounted for.

Any advice?

- Verified access to the SQL Server Express server
- Verified read and write access to the target database
- Verified TCP is enabled on the server using port 1433
- Can use the same ODBC connection in Crystal Reports with no issues
- SQL Browser service is running on the server